# What other writings from the Constitutional Convention corroborate or dispute the definition of the duties of electors in Federalist Papers #68?

Tags: united-states, 18th-century

Is anyone here familiar with the details of the Constitutional Convention of 1787 enough to know if any of the actual participants of that event left any writings that either corroboration or dispute the duties of the presidential electors as described in [Federalist Paper #68](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federalist_No._68) ? Minutes of the convention? memoirs? personal letters? etc...

Comment: How does this question differ from this one: [Is there any documentation on the creation of article 1 section II of the US Constitution?](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/33841/is-there-any-documentation-on-the-creation-of-article-1-section-ii-of-the-us-con/33864#33864) I ask because in researching my answer to that, I looked at FP68. If I were to answer this, I'm not sure my answer would be any different than my answer there, just turned around.

Comment: @T.E.D. -- I had not seen your question and I am very grateful for the lead on Farrand's work, an excellent resource. Unfortunately your answer on that particular question goes to the why of the electoral college's existence but does not address the intended duties of the electors themselves. FP68 talks about their function as one of deliberation and reason and I have asked about that specific question in the Law SE, but I wanted to know what historic documents might be available to the courts for helping to discern the Framer's intent on the role of the electors.